# Unable to use builtin traits From and PartialOrd for Box object bounds

Tags: rust

Admittedly, I'm fairly new to Rust, but I love what I'm seeing so far. That said, I'm running into an issue where I'm getting the error:

```
error: only the builtin traits can be used as closure or object bounds [E0225]
defaults: HashMap<String, Box<Any + From<String> + PartialOrd>>,
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

for the following code:

```
pub struct Builder {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    defaults: HashMap<String, Box<Any + From<String> + PartialOrd>>,                                                                                                                                                                           
    ...
}
```

If I remove the bound on `From` I get the same error but for `PartialOrd`. I don't understand why since I'm fairly certain both `From` and `PartialOrd` are builtin traits. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ rustc --explain E0225
You attempted to use multiple types as bounds for a closure or trait object.
Rust does not currently support this. A simple example that causes this error:

fn main() {
    let _: Box<std::io::Read+std::io::Write>;
}

Builtin traits are an exception to this rule: it's possible to have bounds of
one non-builtin type, plus any number of builtin types. For example, the
following compiles correctly:

fn main() {
    let _: Box<std::io::Read+Copy+Sync>;
}
```

`PartialOrd` and `From` aren't built-in, they're defined in the standard library. Traits like `Copy` and `Sync` are built-in.

You can work around this by defining a new trait with the traits you want as supertraits:

```
trait MyTrait: Any + From<String> + PartialOrd {}
```

Then you can provide a blanket impl for all types that implement all of the traits you want (you can specify multiple traits in bounds, but not in trait objects):

```
impl<T> MyTrait for T where T: Any + From<String> + PartialOrd {}
```

Comment: Note: niko was mentioning thinking of *super-*fat pointers, today fat pointers are (pointer to v-table, pointer to data) and tomorrow they could be (pointer to v-table 0, pointer to v-table 1, ..., pointer to data). This would, in turn, allow having a `Read + Write` bound.

Comment: Unfortunately aliasing the traits I wanted into a super trait didn't work either. I've decided to restructure how I'm storing my defaults to store `HashMap<String, String>` and then have a method `pub fn get_value<T: FromStr>(...) {}`. Seems like a decent alternative, but I'm open to suggestions if anyone has any ideas.

@MatthieuM. That would be awesome!!

Comment: @mattforni: Aliasing into a super-trait *should* work! You may want to ask a question as to why it didn't.